# Receive the text from an element

Tags: javascript

From an element like this:

```
<time index = "check">example text</time>
```

It is possible to receive the innerText with a query like this:

```
querySelectorAll('time').innerText
```

How is it possible to receive the innerText of the index element (check) using a query like this?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a collection of all the matching elements. Use `querySelector` which returns the first matching element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure what you mean. The value of `ìndex`? Or the inner text of `<time index="check">`? So

```js
// get value of index-attribute of the `time` element
console.log(document.querySelector("time").getAttribute("index"));

// or if you need the element with attribute 'index' and index-value 'check'
console.log(document.querySelector("time[index='check']").textContent);

// or if you want to query multiple 'time' elements ...
console.log(
  [...document.querySelectorAll("time")]
    .map( elem => elem.getAttribute("index") )
);

console.log(
  [...document.querySelectorAll("time")]
    .map( elem => elem.textContent )
);
```

```css
time {display: block}
```

```html
<time index = "check">example text check</time>
<time index = "check2">example text check 2</time>
<time index = "check3">example text check 3</time>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the attribute to `querySelectorAll` like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[index="check"]')[0].innerText;
```

It also works for `querySelector`

```
document.querySelector('[index="check"]').innerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a collection, not a single element.

Use `querySelector()` with more specific selector to target the specific `<time>` you want

```js
const t = document.querySelector('time[index="check"]').innerText

console.log(t)
```

```html
<time index = "check">example text</time>
```